# Группировка в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, group-by

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT billing_country
FROM (SELECT billing_country,
             EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(invoice_date AS date)) AS month_of_invoice,
               AVG(total) AS avg_total
      FROM invoice
      WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(invoice_date AS date)) = 2009
      GROUP BY billing_country, month_of_invoice) AS new
WHERE month_of_invoice IN (2, 5, 7, 10)
GROUP BY billing_country
HAVING SUM(avg_total) > 10;
```

Почему в подзапросе нужно обязательно ставить месяц от даты в группировку? И почему в новом запросе опять нужна группировка?

Comment: *Почему в подзапросе нужно обязательно ставить месяц от даты в группировку?* Чтобы сделать по нему отбор во внешнем запросе. *почему в новом запросе опять нужна группировка?* Чтобы определить, что суммировать. PS. А что, `invoice_date` строковое, что ли? а если нет - нафига там CAST?